# Row copied having double entry

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to copy the data-based value in Column 12, but the row data is entered twice in the target sheet, may I know where did I go wrong here?

```js
    function onEdit(event) {
    
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
      var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
    
      if(s.getName() == "Sold Vehicle Review Data" && r.getColumn() == 12 && r.getValue() == "Received") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Reviews");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);  
      }
    }
```

Comment: From your situation and script, I thought that you might install the installable OnEdit trigger to `onEdit()`. If my understanding is correct, please remove the installable trigger. Because your script can work as the simple trigger. When the installable OnEdit trigger is installed to the function `onEdit`, when the cell is edited, `onEdit` is run 2 times. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you Very much... I was puzzled and couldn't figure it out what went wrong :) Thank you for solving my problem. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set an installable trigger which made the double entry, All you have to do is to remove the installed trigger and let work on simple trigger.

Thank you @Tanaike for resolving my Issue.

Comment: As the additional information, when `onEdit()` is installed as the installable OnEdit trigger and a cell is edited, `onEdit` is run 2 times with the asynchronous process. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/88f7fd5ed14da5e9afde18310da61cb5) By this, I think that there might be the case that the value is not added 2 times.