# I need to remove the format on the copied content and paste in new sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is relating to this question [Row copied having double entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949797/row-copied-having-double-entry)

I'm copying a row to another google sheet but I want the clear the format from the data, I tried .clearFormat() and .getDisplayValue() but it still copies the entire format with colors and drop down list,

Can you tell me how to remove the formats when copying the data to another sheet.

This is the code.

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "ABC" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getDisplayValue() == "Done" ) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("XYZ");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    
  } 
}
```

Comment: simply replace copyTo with setValues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.copyTo(target, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)`.

Comment: Reference for this method: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,CopyPasteType,Boolean)